# What has been the effect of the new Area 51 layout?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I really like splitting the proposals into new categories on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) but I have personally noticed that I have spent less time there, particularly looking at the **new proposals**. I expect that is just me personally but I was wondering if there is any **objective data**.

So does anyone have any **data** to show the effect of the new Area 51 layout, specifically:

1. Have there been more proposals or less?
2. Have there been more active users?
3. Have there been more example questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There hasn't been a significant uptick in activity since the redesign (2011-01-27):

**Proposals**

[image]

**Users**

[image]